# Withdrawing ether from smart contract to a specific account using web3

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have a function in my smart contract as follows:

```
function transferToaddress(address payable addressToSend) public payable{
    addressToSend.transfer(0.5 ether);
}
```

From my front-end, I'm calling the above function as follows:

```
var response = await this.contract.transferToaddress(vm.userAccountAddress,{
   from: vm.userAccountAddress,
   gas: vm.gas
})
```

The transaction fails. My contract has some balance. On a click of a button I want some ether (0.5 in this case) to get transferred from my smart contract to the address passed to the function.
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
var response = await this.contract.transferToaddress(vm.userAccountAddress)
.send({ from: vm.userAccountAddress, gas: vm.gas })
```

You missed the send keyword

Answer (score 0):

Contract should not be payable as user is getting ether and it's not supplying ether.

```
function transferToaddress(address payable addressToSend) public{
    addressToSend.transfer(0.5 ether);
}

var response = await this.contract.transferToaddress(vm.userAccountAddress)
    .send({ from: vm.userAccountAddress, gas: vm.gas })
```